# Declaring array before or inside loop

Tags: c, memory-management

What is more effective?

Declaring array e.g. char buffer[4096] before loop and in each iteration clear its content by strlcpy or declare array inside the loop with initial "" value?

```
char buffer[4096] = "";
while(sth)
{
   strlcpy(buffer,"",sizeof(buffer));
   //some action;
}
```

vs

```
while(sth)
{
   char buffer[4096] = "";
  //some action;
}
```

Comment: *"What is more effective?"* - "Effective" in what regard?

Comment: I don't think there is too much difference between

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's probably no significant difference between the two. The only way to be sure would be to benchmark or look at the assembly generated by the compiler.

The second example is clearer and would be preferred.

Answer (score 3):

Neither, there is no reason to clear the entire buffer if it's merely to be used as a string buffer. All you need to do is ensure that a NUL byte `\0` is appended to the end of the relevant string.

If you want to guarantee that the str* functions start at the beginning of `buffer`, a simple `*buffer = '\0'` is all that is needed for the reason mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

The only possible difference in performance is the assignment to the buffer, and this will probably translated by your compiler to a single statement which will be identical to this:

```
*buffer = 0;
```

Compilers will not perform any stack management when you enter the loop.  Whether you define buffer inside or outside the loop doesn't make any difference for the stack.  Place for buffer will be reserved on the stack in the beginning of the routine, regardless of where you define your buffer variable (which doesn't mean that the compiler will allow you to access buffer outside the scope where it is defined).

Even the single assignment shown above will probably be optimized by your compiler if it sees that it doesn't make sense to reinitialize buffer every time over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

To quote Knuth, ["We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization)

Focus on readability.  Optimize when you need to.

Comment: -1 Quote properly please. You got rid of the most important part of that quote!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the first version.  In the first version the array is allocated only once.  In the second version, the array is allocated every iteration of the loop.

Although compilers may optimize the allocation (such as performing only once), I believe factoring it out indicates to the reader that the memory is allocated only once.

This may be nothing to worry about since many platforms allocate on the stack and allocation consists of changing the contents of the stack pointer.

When in doubt profile.

When considering optimizations, don't.  Spend the time making the program correct and robust.